# Halo reach noble achievements

Tags: achievements, halo-reach

Do the halo reach noble achievements need to be completed on the halo reach noble map pack? Such as totally worth it? I know some are specific to the map pack such as the you blew it up achievement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think they need to be. I just got Offensive Driver on Boneyard.

---

**Edit**: You can unlock any achievements apart from the level-specific ones on any map as long as you have downloaded the DLC.

Comment: Yep I don't think I've got any of them on the DLC maps

Answer (score 1):

No it is not nescessary, it worked for me when i took my account across onto another xbox that did not have the Noble DLC; i got the offensive driver and shotgun spree achievments.

Comment: It is necessary to own the DLC to get the achievements. An Xbox that does not have the DLC installed does not matter. All you need to do is have the Noble (or Defiant) DLC and you can get the achievements that go along with it. It does not work if you are on another person's Xbox who has the DLC, and you haven't baught it yet. You must by it to get the achievements.